# GAE read JSON String from Android App

Tags: android, python, json

I want to read a JSON String (getting from my Android App) on the Google App Engine.
But i have no Idea how to solfe this.

These is the code from my App:

```
    JSONObject ob = new JSONObject();
    ob.put("user", "peter");
    ob.put("frage", "frage1");
    ob.put("datumende", "27.4.2012");
    Log.i("json", ob.toString());

    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    byte[] outputBytes = ob.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(outputBytes.length));
    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    os.write(outputBytes);
```

It works. I can read these data from my app engine with

```
getPostData = self.request.body
```

If i write these (getPostData) in the data storage it put out

```
{\"datumende\":\"27.4.2012\",\"user\":\"peter\",\"frage\":\"frage1\"}
```

Also it works.

But how can i split the JSON-String into user, datumende and frage?
I have testet it with

```
x = json.dumps(self.request.body)
y = json.loads(x)
# I thougt in y['user'] is now "peter". But it isnt't
```

Also I testet only

```
x = json.laods(self.request.body)
# I thougt in x['user'] is now "peter". But it isnt't
```

But all do not work.
So, how can I Split the JSON-String into user, frage, datumende?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answere :/

Client-Site (Android):
replace

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

with

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

And these on Server-Site (GAE with Python):

```
lo = self.request.body
fff = json.loads(lo)
name = fff['user']
```